# Error al guardar datos en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, entity-framework

Llevo varios días batallando con este problema a ver si me podrían dar una pequeña ayuda.

Tengo este error:

> "No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna 'CODIGO', tabla
>   'C:\USERS\MAICOLODALIS\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO
>   2010\PROJECTS\SCXP\SCXP\BIN\DEBUG\SCXP.MDF.dbo.PROVEEDORES'. La
>   columna no admite valores NULL. Error de INSERT. Se terminó la
>   instrucción."

este es mi codigo:

```
    Public Shared Sub AGREGARPROVEEDOR(ByVal codigo As String,
                                   ByVal nombres As String,
                                   ByVal apellidos As String,
                                   ByVal direccion As String,
                                   ByVal ciudad As String,
                                   ByVal telefono As String)
    Using BD As New SCXPEntities1
        BD.PROVEEDORES.AddObject(New PROVEEDORE() With {.CODIGO = codigo,
                                                        .NOMBRES = nombres,
                                                        .APELLIDOS = apellidos,
                                                        .DIRECCION = direccion,
                                                        .CIUDAD = ciudad,
                                                        .TELEFONO = telefono})
        BD.SaveChanges()
    End Using
End Sub
```

necesito su ayuda :(

Comment: parece que estas pasandole null al parametro codigo. Haz intentado depurarlo para ver de donde proviene el valor. Este problema no esta aquí, esta antes de llamar a AGREGARPROVEEDOR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que la columna `código` no admite valores `null`, lo mas probable es que esta columna sea la clave primaria de tu tabla o una clave única.

Lo que tendrías que hacer para solucionarlo es asignar un valor a esta columna.

O mejor aún, antes de intentar insertar los valor en la base de datos, comprobar si los valores asignados son los correctos y si no es así mostrar los mensajes oportunos al usuario.

**Actualización:**

Como decía, tienes que asegurarte que la propiedad `Código` tiene un valor antes de realizar la llamada a la base de datos para conseguir dos cosas:

1. Evitar que se produzca el error de base de datos (y sobre ocultarseloal usuario porque puedes desvelar detalles podrían comprometer la seguridad de tu aplicación)
2. Mostrar un mensaje "amigable" para que el usuario entienda lo que ocurre y pueda arreglarlo.

Esto se puede implementar de muchas maneras. Una forma sencilla de hacerlo podría ser convertir tu método en una función que devuelva un `booleano` si se han guardado los datos y una lista con los errores a mostrar al usuario.

El código podría ser algo así *(cuidado que yo soy de C# y he usado el [conversor de Telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/) para este código)*

```
Public Shared Function AGREGARPROVEEDOR(codigo As String, _
    nombres As String, _
    apellidos As String, _
    direccion As String, _
    ciudad As String, _
    telefono As String, _
    ByRef errores As String()) As Boolean

    errors = New List(Of String)()

    ' Comprobar 
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(codigo) Then
        errors.Add("Debe establecer el código del proveedor.")
    End If

    'TODO: Realizar otras comprobaciones

    ' Salir en caso de no pasar las validaciones
    If errors.Count > 0 Then
        Return False
    End If

    Using BD As New SCXPEntities1()
        BD.PROVEEDORES.AddObject(New PROVEEDORE() With { _
            Key .CODIGO = codigo, _
            Key .NOMBRES = nombres, _
            Key .APELLIDOS = apellidos, _
            Key .DIRECCION = direccion, _
            Key .CIUDAD = ciudad, _
            Key .TELEFONO = telefono _
        })
        BD.SaveChanges()
    End Using
    Return True
End Function
```

Otra forma de resolverlo sería usando el motor de validaciones que proporciona el propio Entity Framework como se explica en [este artículo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx) (en inglés)

Comment: estas en toda la razon es una clave primaria, pero nose por que me da error de valores, puedes explicarme bien como solucionar eso

Comment: Hola @MaicolOdalis he actualizado mi respuesta, espero aclarar tus dudas. Saludos

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS EL PROBLEMA ESTABA HAY Y EN EL FORMULARIO DE AGREGACION PERO GRACIAS ATI LO SOLUCIONE, QUISIERA QUE ME DIERAS TU SKYPE O WHATSAPP Y ASI ME EXPLICAS VARIAS COSAS QUE QUISIERA APRENDER

Comment: De nada @MaicolOdalis. Con respecto a tu petición, siento decirte que no puedo atenderte de esa forma tan individualizada porque no dispongo del tiempo necesario, aunque puedes encontrarme en Twitter como **rsciriano**. Además pienso que es mejor hacerlo en plataformas como esta porque **beneficia a la comunidad**. **S.O.** es un buen sitio para aprender y con mucha gente, como yo,  dispuesta a ayudar. Mi recomendación es que agrupes esas dudas y vayas preguntando por aquí. **Es muy importante que tus preguntas sean concretas y que estén trabajadas porque será más fácil ayudarte**. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

El mismo mensaje de error describe la situación:

> "No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna 'CODIGO', tabla
>   dbo.PROVEEDORES"

Puedes modificar la columna 'CODIGO' de tu tabla PROVEEDORES para que acepte valores nulos mediante un script por medio de [**Alter Table**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx).

O modifica directamente en SQL Server la propiedad para aceptar nulos de tu campo ´'CODIGO´´ seleccionando el atributo "`Allow Nulls`":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el ejemplo para que tengas tambien una idea para cuando no te deje usar valores NULL, yo los hago siempre en la consulta; aquí dejo un ejemplo de como lo he hecho:

create procedure SP_MANTENIMIENTO_RUTA 
@OPERACION INT, 
@CODIGO INT, 
@Localidad_Rt varchar(150), 
@Descripcion_Rt varchar(150), 
@SubRuta bit, 
@Estado_Rt bit, 
@LimiteCreditRuta decimal(18,2) 
AS
BEGIN

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- INSERT
IF @OPERACION = 1
BEGIN
DECLARE @MAXIMO INT
SET @MAXIMO = (SELECT MAX(ISNULL(Ruta_ID,0)) + 1 AS MAXIMO FROM Logic_Ruta)
    INSERT INTO Logic_Ruta(Ruta_ID,Localidad_Rt, Descripciòn_Rt, SubRuta, Estado_Rt, LimiteCreditRuta)
        values (@MAXIMO,@Localidad_Rt,@Descripcion_Rt,@SubRuta,@Estado_Rt, @LimiteCreditRuta )
END
--Actualiza
IF @OPERACION = 2
BEGIN
    UPDATE Logic_Ruta SET Localidad_Rt = @Localidad_Rt, Descripciòn_Rt = @Descripcion_Rt,SubRuta =@SubRuta, Estado_Rt = @Estado_Rt, LimiteCreditRuta= @LimiteCreditRuta
        WHERE Ruta_ID = @CODIGO
END
--CARGA GRID
IF @OPERACION = 3
BEGIN
SELECT Ruta_ID AS CODIGO,Localidad_Rt AS Localidad_Rt, Descripciòn_Rt AS Descripcion_Rt, SubRuta AS SubRuta, Estado_Rt as Estado_Rt, LimiteCreditRuta AS LimiteCreditRuta
     FROM Logic_Ruta
END
```

END